# after update to Magento 1.9.1 PayPal is disabled!

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

after update from 1.7.2 to the version 1.9.1 the PayPal payment is disabled.
I cannot activate it. Look to the picture.

[image]

The select box is grey and I cannot activate it. :(

Can anybody give me a help.

Comment: you need to re-enter credentials or check for errors in console.

Comment: Hello, I have it done BUT the same problem. The select box is always grey and I can not activate it. :(

Comment: I have installed fresh 1.9.1 version with out sample data and I have same problem, I cannot activate PayPal!  Is it a bug?

Comment: are you using German translations? can you try with English store? this is the only way i can see it might mess up your page.

Answer (score 1):

now check fields i have and yours, you have something definitely wrong there. and i tested on magento demo site, Magento ver. 1.9.1.0, and if you choose API Signature there must be Signature field, not Certificate. so this must be your modifications, javascript errors, or broken upgrade all together.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
You should see an error in the console on `forms.js` as mentioned above.
I had to clear the magento cache and browser cache. 
Makes sure the `form.js` your loading has the **copyright of "2006-2016"** then you'll know your hitting the latest file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was js error on this page.

So please check have you really updated file

> js/mage/adminhtml/form.js

also try clearing the cache

Comment: When i upgraded 1.9 to 1.9.1 using the Downloader it failed to download a lot of files, i ended up cp'ing the tarball over the top.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all these fields filled in. 
For example, if Email is left out, the enable option will stay grayed out.

.[image: Required fields]